# How do I use UIActionSheet choice to update a dynamic label?

Tags: ios, swift, uiactionsheet

I am a noob, so please forgive me if this question is simple.

I have created a UIActionSheet that pops up with multiple choices and based on whatever the user selects I want to update a dynamic label.  I know how to make the label, but I can't figure out what I'm missing to have the choice update the label.  Can anyone help me with what I'm supposed to add?

My code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let oneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "A", style: .Default) { (_) in }
    let twoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "B", style: .Default) { (_) in }
    let threeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "C", style: .Default) { (_) in }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action) in
        // ...
    }

    alertController.addAction(oneAction)
    alertController.addAction(twoAction)

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)




    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in the `UIAlertAction`:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: UIButton)
{

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    let oneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "A", style: .Default) { (_) in
        // Update Label here
        yourLabel.text = "A"
    }

    let twoAction = UIAlertAction(title: "B", style: .Default) { (_) in
        // Update Label here
        yourLabel.text = "B"
    }

    let threeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "C", style: .Default) { (_) in
        // Update Label here
        yourLabel.text = "C"
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action) in
        // Update Label here
        yourLabel.text = "Cancel Clicked"
    }

    alertController.addAction(oneAction)
    alertController.addAction(twoAction)
    alertController.addAction(threeAction)
    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the label in the handler. Something like this.

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default) { (action) in
        // ...
    self.theLabel.text = "Cancel"
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying ViewController does not have a member named theLabel

Comment: You can replace it with your `UILabel` object, assuming you have it defined in your ViewController.

Comment: I didn't have the outlet set up correctly.  Once I did, it worked like a charm.